# Issues debugging Tizen .NET app on Samsung Tizen 5.5 TV Emulator

Tags: xamarin, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-tv, tizen-tv-emulator

It seems that there are issues with running and debugging Tizen .NET (Xamarin Forms) apps on Tizen emulators.

My environment is a Windows 10 machine, with the latest 2004 version. For development I tried both Visual Studio Professional 2019 (v16.6.2) and VS Professional 2017 (v15.9.24) with the VS Tools for Tizen extension.

I am able to deploy the application on the emulator however cannot debug, VS fails with the message `Unable to start debugging. The system cannot find the specified file` and in the console output I can see an the message `[StdErr] error: cannot remove forward listener`.

Does anyone have any idea? Is there some magical software combination that I can use to make this work or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you see 'Launch Tizen Emulator' or a device name in the VS toolbar?

Comment: Yes, I can see the "Launch Tizen Emulator" when there is no Samsung TV emulator on  and I can see the Image name when the emulator is on.

Comment: @SwiftKim if you have any other ideas or things to check, I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: I don't quite have an idea. I reported to the Tizen SDK team and I hope they can take a look.

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced no end of troubles with Visual Studio Tools for Tizen.  I nearly gave up today completely, I've spent weeks just getting it to partially work, and only a day or two of actual development, but finally figured out a few things that might be unique to my system or most likely are just missing in the documentation (which is not rare for Samsung at all).

First up, the emulator issue. I'm assuming you've been through the certificate manager and generated a Samsung certificate (make sure to have installed the extensions in the package manager, Samsung wearable extensions and Samsung certificate extensions then run through and create your Samsung certificate in certificate manager).

So now in the emulator manager try "right" clicking the specific emulator and select allow to install applications. It might now indicate it has installed a certificate.  This is a good sign.  Also i assume you know not to use HyperV (you can look up how to create a bootloader that can enable you to dual boot windows where HyperV can be disabled in one and enabled in your default).

Assuming that worked and you still can't debug i found that you may need to build the application (clean the build for good measure first - remember this - it can save you often if things don't work when you change something), then click Start without Debugging from visual studio. This should install the application to the device and launch it, fingers crossed.  Now if that worked, and your application is now running in emulator or on device, you may find that future attempts now to debug it will work.

The final thing which has nearly made me give up is the update to my watch.  It recently updated and i noted the new tizen version reported by the watch is 5.5.  So naturally i went ahead and changed the api level to 5.5 and hey presto it all just seemed to work and i could continue as before, debugging and changing things happily.  Then i uninstalled the application for a dry run and since then I spent a week trying to figure out why it will not reinstall the application on the emulator or the watch ( (it was a week ago i upgraded to api 5.5 and there were no issues, so that was way down the list of anything that could go wrong). I reinstalled etc, did the whole gamut of things all to no avail. At some point i got it working on the emulator but not the watch, finally today i have it working on both and don't wish to develop anything, i'm spent.

So that final issue was resoled by moving the projects back to api 4.0 and they would now reinstall on my watch and my emulator (use the Start without Debugging trick as well to install it first).  Also (my fault - why it worked on emulator but not watch at some point) beware if you have one that is api 4 and one is api 5.5 - which i did while i was testing the above (one is a service the other the ui - they were at different api levels - that will not work on a device - but was happy on the emulator).

If none of that works for you, i'd advise give up, life is too short.

Cheers

Comment: Yup, I gave up. Thanks for providing your input on this issue. This way Samsung might see that there are multiple devs running into issues and might want to work on improving their dev experience

Comment: sdb server is usally the problem. it has client and server version and when you update extension through VS. it causes errors. it requires usually fresh instal using Tizen Studio.